# How to pass and remove a selected options value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to have the selected options value pass when I click the Add Another Worker button and have the pre `selected="selected"` option removed and placed on the new selected option.

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.worker').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        var title = $('.title').val();

        var worker = '<select name="title[]" class="title"><option value="Select a Title" selected="selected">Select a Title</option><option value="Boss">Boss</option><option value="Worker">Worker</option><option value="Manager">Manager</option></select>';

        $('.add-more').append(worker);


        $('.title:first').val('Select a Title');
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="worker-container-last">
            <label class="worker-label">
                <select name="title[]" class="title">
                    <option value="Select a Title" selected="selected">Select a Title</option>
                    <option value="Boss">Boss</option>
                    <option value="Worker">Worker</option>
                    <option value="Manager">Manager</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="add-more"></div>
        <div><a class="worker" title="" href="">Add Another Worker</a></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is a link to my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jxqyn4rg/

Comment: could you give a more descriptive explanation on what should really happen

Comment: I'm trying to pass the selected value to the generated select menu when the add another worker button is clicked.

Comment: could you try this working link [link](http://codepen.io/yhudhaifa/pen/JKaBbB)

Comment: @Hudhaifa Yoosuf the code seems to be working fine but is there another way to shorten the code so it wont be so repetitive other wise this is what I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: the answer is below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to append new `select` to your `div` on click of a button. If so, A simple way would be restructure your html to have `.add-more` `div` before your actual (or initial select box).

```
<ul>
    <li>
<div class="add-more"></div>
        <div class="worker-container-last">
            <label class="worker-label">
                <select name="title[]" class="title">
                    <option value="Select a Title" selected="selected">Select a Title</option>
                    <option value="Boss">Boss</option>
                    <option value="Worker">Worker</option>
                    <option value="Manager">Manager</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </div>

        <div><a class="worker" title="" href="">Add Another Worker</a></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the in your js use `prepend` instead of `append` something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.worker').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        var title = $('.title').val();

        var worker = '<li><select name="title[]" class="title"><option value="Select a Title" selected="selected">Select a Title</option><option value="Boss">Boss</option><option value="Worker">Worker</option><option value="Manager">Manager</option></select></li>';

        $('.add-more').prepend(worker);


        //$('.title:first').val('Select a Title');
    });
});
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nje3opu7/

**EDIT** if you dont want to change your `HTML` or `CSS` as you said in your comments you could modify your jQuery logic to following to achieve what you're after:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.worker').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();


      var getValue = $('.title:first').val()  
      var worker = '<select name="title[]" class=" newSelect title"><option value="Select a Title" selected="selected">Select a Title</option><option value="Boss">Boss</option><option value="Worker">Worker</option><option value="Manager">Manager</option></select>';
      $('.add-more').append(worker);
      $('.title:eq('+$('.newSelect').length+')').val(getValue);

      $('.title:first').val('Select a Title');
    });
});
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/97tnnyj0/

**Edit2:** Even @KAD Code would work fine if you replace:

`jqueryselect.val($('.title:last').val());` with `jqueryselect.val($('.title:first').val());`

Comment: But I really need the `<div class="add-more"></div>` to be left in its original place.

Comment: Not really, I need the css code to stay the same as well as the html code

Answer (score 1):

You can create a jquery object directly from the html string of the select and set its value with the value of the last `.title` select:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.worker').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        var title = $('.title').val();

        var worker = '<select name="title[]" class="title"><option value="Select a Title" selected="selected">Select a Title</option><option value="Boss">Boss</option><option value="Worker">Worker</option><option value="Manager">Manager</option></select>';

        // create the jquery object and set the value
        var jqueryselect = $(worker);
        jqueryselect.val($('.title:first').val());

        // this can be combined to one line also
        // $(worker).val($('.title:first').val());

        $('.add-more').append(jqueryselect);


        $('.title:first').val('Select a Title');
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jxqyn4rg/9/

Comment: This seems to pass the same value from the first add to all the other added options.

Comment: No, change the value when creating a new one, you get the value of the last select

Comment: I keep getting the same value of the first selected option no matter how many time I select a different option and add it.

Answer (score 1):

Could You Try This

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="worker-container-last">
            <label class="worker-label">
                <select name="title[]" class="title" id="select1">
                    <option value="Select a Title" selected="selected">Select a Title</option>
                    <option value="Boss">Boss</option>
                    <option value="Worker">Worker</option>
                    <option value="Manager">Manager</option>
                </select>
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="add-more"></div>
        <div><a class="worker" title="" href="">Add Another Worker</a></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Script**

```
$('.worker').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        debugger;

        var title = $('.title').val();

  var selected = $('#select1').val();

  var worker = '<select name="title[]" class="title" >';
  worker +='<option value="Select a Title">Select a Title</option>';

  if(selected=="Boss"){
         worker+='<option value="Boss" selected="selected">Boss</option>' ;
     worker+='<option value="Worker">Worker</option>' ;
     worker+='<option value="Manager">Manager</option>' ;
  }      
  else if (selected=="Worker"){
      worker+='<option value="Boss" >Boss</option>';
     worker+='<option value="Worker" selected="selected">Worker</option>' ;
       worker+='<option value="Manager">Manager</option>' ;
  }
  else if (selected=="Manager"){
   worker+='<option value="Boss" >Boss</option>';
     worker+='<option value="Worker">Worker</option>'; 
     worker+='<option value="Manager" selected="selected">Manager</option>' ;
  }
  else{
     worker+='<option value="Boss">Boss</option>' ;
     worker+='<option value="Worker">Worker</option>' ;
     worker+='<option value="Manager">Manager</option>' ;
  }


        $('.add-more').append(worker);


        $('.title:first').val('Select a Title');
    });
});
```

Working Link

[Code Pen Link](http://codepen.io/yhudhaifa/pen/JKaBbB)